# How to set an index within multiindex for datetime?

Tags: pandas

I have this df:

```
                      open     high      low    close    volume
date       symbol                                              
2014-02-20 AAPL    69.9986  70.5252  69.4746  69.7569  76529103
           MSFT    33.5650  33.8331  33.4087  33.7259  27541038
2014-02-21 AAPL    69.9727  70.2061  68.8967  68.9821  69757247
           MSFT    33.8956  34.2619  33.8241  33.9313  38030656
2014-02-24 AAPL    68.7063  69.5954  68.6104  69.2841  72364950
           MSFT    33.6723  33.9269  33.5382  33.6723  32143395
```

which is returned from here:

```
from datetime import datetime
from iexfinance.stocks import get_historical_data
from pandas_datareader import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

start =  '2014-01-01'
end = datetime.today().utcnow()
symbol = ['AAPL', 'MSFT']

prices = pd.DataFrame()
datasets_test = []
for d in symbol:
    data_original = data.DataReader(d, 'iex', start, end)
    data_original['symbol'] = d
    prices = pd.concat([prices,data_original],axis=0)
prices = prices.set_index(['symbol'], append=True)
prices.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

when trying to get the day of the week:

```
A['day_of_week'] = features.index.get_level_values('date').weekday
```

I get error:

> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'weekday'

I tried to change the date index to date time with

```
prices['date'] = pd.to_datetime(prices['date'])
```

but got this error:

> KeyError: 'date'

Any idea how to keep 2 indexs, date + symbol but to change one of them (date) tp datetime so I could get the day of the week?

Comment: Try df.index.levels[0] = pd.to_datetime(df.index.levels[0])

Comment: TypeError: 'FrozenList' does not support mutable operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `date` level of the index contains strings, not datetime objects. One solution is to reset all MultiIndex levels into columns, convert the `date` column to datetime, and set the MultiIndex back. Then you can proceed with pandas datetime accessors like `.weekday` in the usual way.

```
prices = prices.reset_index()
prices['date'] = pd.to_datetime(prices['date'])
prices = prices.set_index(['date', 'symbol'])

prices.index.get_level_values('date').weekday
Int64Index([3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2,
            ...
            1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1],
           dtype='int64', name='date', length=2516)
```